# Using coalesce function with many variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two datasets with similar variables. dataset2 has values of of variables that were not captured in dataset2. My aim is to use the dataset2 variables to fill the corresponding values in variables in dataset1. Is there a way to achieve this. It is possible to use coalesce but listing all the variables is a bit cumbersome.

```
library(dplyr)


dat1 <- tibble(
  id = c("soo1", "soo2", "soo3", "soo4"),
  a1= c("Test", "Tested", "Testing", NA),
  a2= c("Math", "Eng", NA, "French"),
  a3= c("Science", NA, "Biology", "Chem"))


dat2 <- tibble(
  id = c("soo1", "soo2", "soo3", "soo4"),
  a1= c(NA, NA, NA, "Tested"),
  a2= c("Math", NA, "UK", NA),
  a3= c("Science", "Physic", NA, NA))

dat1 %>%
  inner_join(dat2, by = "id") %>%
  mutate(a1 = coalesce(a1.x, a1.y),
         a2 = coalesce(a2.x, a2.y))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also `fill` your values "downup" per group for every column like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat1 <- tibble(
  id = c("soo1", "soo2", "soo3", "soo4"),
  a1= c("Test", "Tested", "Testing", NA),
  a2= c("Math", "Eng", NA, "French"),
  a3= c("Science", NA, "Biology", "Chem"))


dat2 <- tibble(
  id = c("soo1", "soo2", "soo3", "soo4"),
  a1= c(NA, NA, NA, "Tested"),
  a2= c("Math", NA, "UK", NA),
  a3= c("Science", "Physic", NA, NA))

dat1 %>%
  bind_rows(dat2) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>%
  slice(1)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#> # Groups:   id [4]
#>   id    a1      a2     a3     
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  
#> 1 soo1  Test    Math   Science
#> 2 soo2  Tested  Eng    Physic 
#> 3 soo3  Testing UK     Biology
#> 4 soo4  Tested  French Chem
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, based on `powerjoin`:

```r
library(powerjoin)
library(tibble)

power_inner_join(dat1, dat2, by = "id", conflict = coalesce_xy)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   id    a1      a2     a3     
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  
#> 1 soo1  Test    Math   Science
#> 2 soo2  Tested  Eng    Physic 
#> 3 soo3  Testing UK     Biology
#> 4 soo4  Tested  French Chem
```

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr`, we may use `rows_patch`

```
library(dplyr)
rows_patch(dat1, dat2, by = 'id')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  id    a1      a2     a3     
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  
1 soo1  Test    Math   Science
2 soo2  Tested  Eng    Physic 
3 soo3  Testing UK     Biology
4 soo4  Tested  French Chem
```

Comment: Interesting. Discovered this today!